# How to Disable Speed Dial?

Tags: samsung, calls, 4.3-jelly-bean, talk-back, explore-by-touch

I have a Samsung phone, tracphone, with andriod 4.3.

talk back and [explore by touch](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006598?hl=en) are both active.

When trying to use the phone, very short pauses are interpreted as a long pause, bringing up the speed dial dialog box.  This makes it very difficult for a new smart phone user to make a phone call.

I did find the option to change the pause length on the device, but this is NOT a solution to the issue.

I have searched and am not able to find a way to disable or completely remove speed dial.  It will never be used, so I am ok with completely removing it from the phone.  Searching Google only returns results on how to delete or modify a speed dial number.

Answer (score 1):

While this solution does not disable speed dial it does make the phone less sensitive to pauses, and makes dialing when talk back and explore by touch are both active much friendlier.

Suggestion by a family friend, worked great thank you.

Settings > Language & Input > Pointer Speed

Adjust the slide setting by touching the end of the slide (does not slide on our phone when talk back and explore by touch are both active.

On our phone, sliding to right (100%) significantly decreased the number of times the speed dial dialog box popped up.